# How to use actionbarsherlock for Google maps menu?

Tags: android, google-maps, actionbarsherlock

Please view image of Google maps fig 1. from the link below:

http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/search-%E2%80%93-main-menu

[image: Google maps fig 1]

Currently `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}` will add menu to action bar. How to create menu below?

Finally:

1. How do I control both Menu options below and Action bar above.
2. Is there any source code or demo for the same available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On pre-Honeycomb the overflow menu for ActionBarSherlock (that is, item that do not fit into the action bar) will be placed in the normal options menu by default.

Your posted screenshot can be achieved using the following:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Places")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_places)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    menu.add("Layers")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_layers)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    menu.add("My Location")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    menu.add("Directions")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_directions)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    menu.add("Starred Places").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_starred);
    menu.add("Clear Map").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_clear);
    menu.add("Join Latitude").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_latitude);
    //Whatever else is under the "More" menu
    return true;
}
```

Here's a screenshot from one of the sample application that come with the library demonstrating this on Android 2.3.3:

[image]

When running on a Honeycomb or a ICS device (with no hardware menu button) the overflow menu becomes the last item on the action bar and shows up in a dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you Sir for the reply.I have queries regarding the configuration of Google Maps Action bar with shelockactionbar,As per the document https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps  I need to add actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.0.0.jar to my libs folder which already has android-support-v4.jar.Is there any additional changes in androidmanifest.xml or just the addition of jar file will do? I have gone through the video for config from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY  could you please upload another video for google maps config?It would be of great help.

Comment: For additional queries is it alright if I can contact you at     jakewharton@gmail.com ? I appreciate your help and quick reply.Thanks again Sir.

Comment: I did not make the video and I would prefer if you used the mailing list rather than contacting me directly: http://abs.io/forum

Answer (score 1):

They are mutually exclusive. As of Android v3.0, the menu at the bottom has been replaced with the ActionBar "overflow" (the icon top-right with three dots).

So on Android 3.0 devices, the menu will open top-right, on older devices, it'll appear at the bottom. The image attached shows the Android 4 way of doing things.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ollie for the reply.That means onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {} on mobile would be represented as action bar menu in Tab.right? and additional icons will be represented as overflow menu.

Comment: @OllieC the problem is if we do not have the actionbar in the activity, we can not show the menu in devices that does not have the physical menu button! what is the solution?