# menu items not being added to actionbar in ics

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have added , menu items to my code by :

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar

    menu.add("Save")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is i can view the menu item by clicking on the menu button on the emulator , but why it isn't appearing on the action bar as it is supposed to .

I have 3 tabs in my app , which i've implemented using tabactivity . and i am using actionbrsherlock . 
I can view the menu item on action bar in android 2.3.3 , but not in android 4.0.3 . In 4.0.3 , it just appears when i click on menu button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863403/how-to-use-actionbarsherlock-for-google-maps-menu)

On pre-Honeycomb the overflow menu for ActionBarSherlock (that is, item that do not fit into the action bar) will be placed in the normal options menu by default.

and can try

```
 menu.add("Save")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.save)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

Comment: i just updated my post , actually the problem is that i can't get the menu item on action bar in ICS , it is just appearing on clicking menu button. it's wierd , i know